# Pandas Dataframe Unintended Removing Columns - *Strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am experiencing strange behavior when trying to create a dataframe. I have a list of dicts I am converting to a dataframe. However, in the creation process, two columns are being dropped unintentionally. I am not sure why it is occurring.

Here is my list:

```
    data_income_stmt = [{'ticker': 'ADBE', 'FY': 2017, 'statement': 'income_statement', 'operatingrevenue': 7301505000.0, 'totalrevenue': 7301505000.0, 'operatingcostofrevenue': 1010491000.0, 'totalcostofrevenue': 1010491000.0, 'totalgrossprofit': 6291014000.0, 'sgaexpense': 624706000.0, 'marketingexpense': 2197592000.0, 'rdexpense': 1224059000.0, 'amortizationexpense': 76562000.0, 'totaloperatingexpenses': 4122919000.0, 'totaloperatingincome': 2168095000.0, 'totalinterestexpense': 74402000.0, 'totalinterestincome': 7553000.0, 'otherincome': 36395000.0, 'totalotherincome': -30454000.0, 'totalpretaxincome': 2137641000.0, 'incometaxexpense': 443687000.0, 'netincomecontinuing': 1693954000.0, 'netincome': 1693954000.0, 'netincometocommon': 1693954000.0, 'weightedavebasicsharesos': 493632000.0, 'basiceps': 3.43, 'weightedavedilutedsharesos': 501123000.0, 'dilutedeps': 3.38, 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos': 493900000.0, 'basicdilutedeps': 3.43}, {'ticker': 'ADBE', 'FY': 2016, 'statement': 'income_statement', 'operatingrevenue': 5854430000.0, 'totalrevenue': 5854430000.0, 'operatingcostofrevenue': 819908000.0, 'totalcostofrevenue': 819908000.0, 'totalgrossprofit': 5034522000.0, 'sgaexpense': 576202000.0, 'marketingexpense': 1910197000.0, 'rdexpense': 975987000.0, 'amortizationexpense': 78534000.0, 'totaloperatingexpenses': 3540920000.0, 'totaloperatingincome': 1493602000.0, 'totalinterestexpense': 70442000.0, 'totalinterestincome': -1570000.0, 'otherincome': 13548000.0, 'totalotherincome': -58464000.0, 'totalpretaxincome': 1435138000.0, 'incometaxexpense': 266356000.0, 'netincomecontinuing': 1168782000.0, 'netincome': 1168782000.0, 'netincometocommon': 1168782000.0, 'weightedavebasicsharesos': 498345000.0, 'basiceps': 2.35, 'weightedavedilutedsharesos': 504299000.0, 'dilutedeps': 2.32, 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos': 497400000.0, 'basicdilutedeps': 2.35}, {'ticker': 'ADBE', 'FY': 2015, 'statement': 'income_statement', 'operatingrevenue': 4795511000.0, 'totalrevenue': 4795511000.0, 'operatingcostofrevenue': 744317000.0, 'totalcostofrevenue': 744317000.0, 'totalgrossprofit': 4051194000.0, 'sgaexpense': 533478000.0, 'marketingexpense': 1683242000.0, 'rdexpense': 862730000.0, 'amortizationexpense': 68649000.0, 'totaloperatingexpenses': 3148099000.0, 'totaloperatingincome': 903095000.0, 'totalinterestexpense': 64184000.0, 'totalinterestincome': 961000.0, 'otherincome': 33909000.0, 'totalotherincome': -29314000.0, 'totalpretaxincome': 873781000.0, 'incometaxexpense': 244230000.0, 'netincomecontinuing': 629551000.0, 'netincome': 629551000.0, 'netincometocommon': 629551000.0, 'weightedavebasicsharesos': 498764000.0, 'basiceps': 1.26, 'weightedavedilutedsharesos': 507164000.0, 'dilutedeps': 1.24, 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos': 499600000.0, 'basicdilutedeps': 1.26}, {'ticker': 'AMZN', 'FY': 2017, 'statement': 'income_statement', 'operatingrevenue': 177866000000.0, 'totalrevenue': 177866000000.0, 'operatingcostofrevenue': 137183000000.0, 'totalcostofrevenue': 137183000000.0, 'totalgrossprofit': 40683000000.0, 'sgaexpense': 3888000000.0, 'marketingexpense': 10069000000.0, 'rdexpense': 22620000000.0, 'totaloperatingexpenses': 36577000000.0, 'totaloperatingincome': 4106000000.0, 'totalinterestexpense': 848000000.0, 'totalinterestincome': 202000000.0, 'otherincome': 346000000.0, 'totalotherincome': -300000000.0, 'totalpretaxincome': 3806000000.0, 'incometaxexpense': 769000000.0, 'othergains': -4000000.0, 'netincomecontinuing': 3033000000.0, 'netincome': 3033000000.0, 'netincometocommon': 3033000000.0, 'weightedavebasicsharesos': 480000000.0, 'basiceps': 6.32, 'weightedavedilutedsharesos': 493000000.0, 'dilutedeps': 6.15, 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos': 479900000.0, 'basicdilutedeps': 6.32}, {'ticker': 'AMZN', 'FY': 2016, 'statement': 'income_statement', 'operatingrevenue': 135987000000.0, 'totalrevenue': 135987000000.0, 'operatingcostofrevenue': 105884000000.0, 'totalcostofrevenue': 105884000000.0, 'totalgrossprofit': 30103000000.0, 'sgaexpense': 2599000000.0, 'marketingexpense': 7233000000.0, 'rdexpense': 16085000000.0, 'totaloperatingexpenses': 25917000000.0, 'totaloperatingincome': 4186000000.0, 'totalinterestexpense': 484000000.0, 'totalinterestincome': 100000000.0, 'otherincome': 90000000.0, 'totalotherincome': -294000000.0, 'totalpretaxincome': 3892000000.0, 'incometaxexpense': 1425000000.0, 'othergains': -96000000.0, 'netincomecontinuing': 2371000000.0, 'netincome': 2371000000.0, 'netincometocommon': 2371000000.0, 'weightedavebasicsharesos': 474000000.0, 'basiceps': 5.01, 'weightedavedilutedsharesos': 484000000.0, 'dilutedeps': 4.9, 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos': 473300000.0, 'basicdilutedeps': 5.01}, {'ticker': 'AMZN', 'FY': 2015, 'statement': 'income_statement', 'operatingrevenue': 107006000000.0, 'totalrevenue': 107006000000.0, 'operatingcostofrevenue': 85061000000.0, 'totalcostofrevenue': 85061000000.0, 'totalgrossprofit': 21945000000.0, 'sgaexpense': 1918000000.0, 'marketingexpense': 5254000000.0, 'rdexpense': 12540000000.0, 'totaloperatingexpenses': 19712000000.0, 'totaloperatingincome': 2233000000.0, 'totalinterestexpense': 459000000.0, 'totalinterestincome': 50000000.0, 'otherincome': -256000000.0, 'totalotherincome': -665000000.0, 'totalpretaxincome': 1568000000.0, 'incometaxexpense': 950000000.0, 'othergains': -22000000.0, 'netincomecontinuing': 596000000.0, 'netincome': 596000000.0, 'netincometocommon': 596000000.0, 'weightedavebasicsharesos': 467000000.0, 'basiceps': 1.28, 'weightedavedilutedsharesos': 477000000.0, 'dilutedeps': 1.25, 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos': 465600000.0, 'basicdilutedeps': 1.28}, {'ticker': 'BA', 'FY': 2017, 'statement': 'income_statement', 'operatingrevenue': 93392000000.0, 'totalrevenue': 93392000000.0, 'operatingcostofrevenue': 76066000000.0, 'totalcostofrevenue': 76066000000.0, 'totalgrossprofit': 17326000000.0, 'sgaexpense': 4094000000.0, 'rdexpense': 3179000000.0, 'otherspecialcharges': -21000000.0, 'totaloperatingexpenses': 7252000000.0, 'totaloperatingincome': 10074000000.0, 'totalinterestexpense': 360000000.0, 'totalinterestincome': 204000000.0, 'otherincome': 129000000.0, 'totalotherincome': -27000000.0, 'totalpretaxincome': 10047000000.0, 'incometaxexpense': 1850000000.0, 'netincomecontinuing': 8197000000.0, 'netincome': 8197000000.0, 'netincometocommon': 8197000000.0, 'weightedavebasicsharesos': 602500000.0, 'basiceps': 13.6, 'weightedavedilutedsharesos': 602500000.0, 'dilutedeps': 13.43, 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos': 602500000.0, 'basicdilutedeps': 13.6, 'cashdividendspershare': 5.97}, {'ticker': 'BA', 'FY': 2016, 'statement': 'income_statement', 'operatingrevenue': 94571000000.0, 'totalrevenue': 94571000000.0, 'operatingcostofrevenue': 80790000000.0, 'totalcostofrevenue': 80790000000.0, 'totalgrossprofit': 13781000000.0, 'sgaexpense': 3616000000.0, 'rdexpense': 4627000000.0, 'otherspecialcharges': 7000000.0, 'totaloperatingexpenses': 8250000000.0, 'totaloperatingincome': 5531000000.0, 'totalinterestexpense': 306000000.0, 'totalinterestincome': 303000000.0, 'otherincome': 40000000.0, 'totalotherincome': 37000000.0, 'totalpretaxincome': 5568000000.0, 'incometaxexpense': 673000000.0, 'netincomecontinuing': 4895000000.0, 'netincome': 4895000000.0, 'netincometocommon': 4895000000.0, 'weightedavebasicsharesos': 635500000.0, 'basiceps': 7.7, 'weightedavedilutedsharesos': 635500000.0, 'dilutedeps': 7.61, 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos': 635500000.0, 'basicdilutedeps': 7.7, 'cashdividendspershare': 4.69}, {'ticker': 'BA', 'FY': 2015, 'statement': 'income_statement', 'operatingrevenue': 96114000000.0, 'totalrevenue': 96114000000.0, 'operatingcostofrevenue': 82088000000.0, 'totalcostofrevenue': 82088000000.0, 'totalgrossprofit': 14026000000.0, 'sgaexpense': 3525000000.0, 'rdexpense': 3331000000.0, 'otherspecialcharges': 1000000.0, 'totaloperatingexpenses': 6857000000.0, 'totaloperatingincome': 7169000000.0, 'totalinterestexpense': 275000000.0, 'totalinterestincome': 274000000.0, 'otherincome': -13000000.0, 'totalotherincome': -14000000.0, 'totalpretaxincome': 7155000000.0, 'incometaxexpense': 1979000000.0, 'netincomecontinuing': 5176000000.0, 'netincome': 5176000000.0, 'netincometocommon': 5176000000.0, 'weightedavebasicsharesos': 686900000.0, 'basiceps': 7.52, 'weightedavedilutedsharesos': 686900000.0, 'dilutedeps': 7.44, 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos': 686900000.0, 'basicdilutedeps': 7.52, 'cashdividendspershare': 3.82}]
```

Here is the code I am using to convert the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_income_stmt)
```

The result is two missing columns: **ticker, statement**

Here the result when running `print(df.columns.values.tolist())`

```
['FY', 'amortizationexpense', 'basicdilutedeps', 'basiceps', 'cashdividendspershare', 'dilutedeps', 'incometaxexpense', 'marketingexpense', 'netincome', 'netincomecontinuing', 'netincometocommon', 'operatingcostofrevenue', 'operatingrevenue', 'othergains', 'otherincome', 'otherspecialcharges', 'rdexpense', 'sgaexpense', 'statement', 'ticker', 'totalcostofrevenue', 'totalgrossprofit', 'totalinterestexpense', 'totalinterestincome', 'totaloperatingexpenses', 'totaloperatingincome', 'totalotherincome', 'totalpretaxincome', 'totalrevenue', 'weightedavebasicdilutedsharesos', 'weightedavebasicsharesos', 'weightedavedilutedsharesos']
```

I am not sure why the columns are being removed/dropped.

Comment: ticker and statement are within your output of df.columns.values.tolist()

Comment: Ok, I don't think they are dropped. When you print `df`, you don't see them because they happen to be in the portion which is hidden in the print due to the large size of the dataframe. Try replacing `ticker ` by `aticker` and you will see they are there

Comment: No. they are still there.

Comment: Your columns are organized in alphabetical order you can find them just after sgaexpense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no columns lost.

Your dataframe has 32 columns

```
len((df.columns.values.tolist()))
```

If you loop through your list, collect all keys and compare them to the dataframe, it's the same.

```
keys = [] 
for e, k in enumerate(data_income_stmt):
    keys.extend(k.keys()) 
    print ('row',e,' keys so far', len(set(keys)),
           'statement found in keys', 'statement' in k.keys(),
           'ticker found in keys', 'ticker' in k.keys())

print('compare columns to keys', set(df.columns.values.tolist()) == set(keys))

print('ticker found in keys', 'ticker' in keys)
print('ticker found in df', 'ticker' in df.columns)
print('statement found in keys', 'statement' in keys)
print('statement found in df', 'statement' in df.columns)
```

This prints

```
row 0  keys so far 29 statement found in keys True ticker found in keys True
row 1  keys so far 29 statement found in keys True ticker found in keys True
row 2  keys so far 29 statement found in keys True ticker found in keys True
row 3  keys so far 30 statement found in keys True ticker found in keys True
row 4  keys so far 30 statement found in keys True ticker found in keys True
row 5  keys so far 30 statement found in keys True ticker found in keys True
row 6  keys so far 32 statement found in keys True ticker found in keys True
row 7  keys so far 32 statement found in keys True ticker found in keys True
row 8  keys so far 32 statement found in keys True ticker found in keys True
compare columns to keys True
ticker found in keys True
ticker found in df True
statement found in keys True
statement found in df True
```

Maybe you are confused by the fact that each dictionary items has 29 keys and not 32 keys. But **statement** and **ticker** are in there.